# Calling angular service from InnerHTML functions

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my Angular 10 app, using `innerHtml` I'm rendering some contents with anchor links.

Now, For each links clicked i need to call a function and which indeed will call angular service.

Below my code, attaching `addEventListener` to all links

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.privacy_policy = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a.privacy_policy');
    this.privacy_policy.forEach((anchor: HTMLAnchorElement) => {
      anchor.addEventListener('click', this.taggingPrivacyPolicy);
    })
  }

  taggingPrivacyPolicy() {
    const eventTag: EventTag = {
      z_eventplace: 'terms_and_conditions',
      z_eventtype: 'privacy_policy',
      z_eventvalue: `${this.brand}_policy`
    };
    this.taggingService.tagEvent(`${this.brand}_policy`, eventTag, 'onclick');
    console.log('clicked');
  }
```

Now, When user clicks on the link i'm getting the below error,

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagEvent' of undefined
```

how to fix this error ?

Comment: Why would generate code with `innerHTML` instead of `*ngFor`?

Comment: it's from API and can't use structural directives, for time being we're stuck with innerHtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably losing `this` reference.
Try this:

`anchor.addEventListener('click', this.taggingPrivacyPolicy.bind(this));`